# How to use constants in %w in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I like to have

```
C1 = 'V1'.freeze
C2 = 'V2'.freeze
```

to become

```
[ 'V1', 'V2' ]
```

When I use

```
%w(V1 V2)
```

I get

```
[ 'V1', 'V2' ]
```

And also when I use

```
%w("#{C1}" "#{C2}")
```

However, I wonder if there is something simpler to use the constants, but without `#{...}`.

Example code:

```
C1 = "vC1".freeze
C2 = "vC2".freeze

puts '-----------a----------'
a  = %w(D1 D2)
puts a.class
puts a

puts '-----------b----------'
b = ["#{C1}", "#{C2}"]
puts b.class
puts b

puts '-----------c----------'
c = %w(C1 C2)
puts c.class
puts c
```

Result:

```
-----------a----------
Array
D1
D2
-----------b----------
Array
vC1
vC2
-----------c----------
Array
C1
C2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is rather simple:

```
[C1, C2]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[ 'V1', 'V2' ]
```